# Interpretation of bit/bytes for defining variables inside a typedef in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C programming. I have been provided with a table which has the inputs defined as follows:

```
fieldA 8 bits
fieldB 5 bits
fieldc 2 bytes
fieldf 6 bits
```

all these fields are part of a input config. Which one is a better way to define the struct for the above?

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned fieldA: 8;  //used char here since inputs can be in hex format (eg 0x45)
   unsigned fieldb: 5;
   unsigned fieldc: 16;
   unsigned fieldf: 6;
} input_cfg;

struct input_cfg {
   unsigned char fieldA;  //used char here since inputs can be in hex format (eg 0x45)
   unsigned char fieldb;
   unsigned char fieldc;
   unsigned char fieldf;
};
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

sksp

Comment: `fieldc` needs at least 2 bytes, so you would need `uint16_t`, `unsigned short` or `unsigned char[2]`

Comment: I think this question needs more context. Are you learning about bit fields in school?

Comment: I need to build a struct for the provided table. searching through web, found two ways to write it. but was not sure which one is better